# Where can i find open source salesforce projects looking for developers?

Tags: open-source

Where can i find open source salesforce projects that are looking for developers.

I have 2 years of experience as salesforce admin and want to sharpen my skills in coding by contributing to open source project.

I searched on sourceforge.net but could not find any.

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have better success on [github](https://github.com/search?o=desc&q=salesforce&s=stars&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93) I believe. Perhaps there aren't a bunch of projects *actively* looking for developers, but there's nothing to stop you from working on some solutions that are out there. If anything, fork something and get creative.

[Visualstrap](https://github.com/Avinava/VisualStrap)

[Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries)

Comment: http://developer.force.com/codeshare can also be a place to look into...

Comment: @Sid, Latest projects point to 2011! I would love to see some life breathed back into that site, but I feel it might be too far gone...

Comment: If you have good experience and want to enhance your knowledge and apply your skills to good work, you can also volunteer for non-profit Organizations. Please check the link http://www.salesforcefoundation.org/volunteers/ for more details. This is not essentially not open source project but looking for developer/admin skillset.

Answer (score 0):

The [foundation has plenty of OSS projects](https://github.com/salesforcefoundation) that always need help, in particular the Nonprofit Starter Pack.